# Adding uncompiled typescript library to Craco config

Tags: reactjs, typescript, craco

I have a "common library" written in Typescript and I want to use it in a couple more projects. I don't want to create a npm package from it, I just want to import it as "uncompiled package" but I'm having trouble setting this up.
I tried adding ts-loader and excluding the module like this:

```
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  use: 'ts-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules\/((?!common-library).)*$/,
});
```

However, this results in Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /path/to/index,tsx.

I also tried using `craco-babel-loader` https://github.com/rjerue/craco-babel-loader, however when adding it to the list of plugins:

```
{
  plugin: rewireBabelLoader,
  options: {
    includes: [resolveApp('node_modules/common-library')],
    excludes: [/node_modules/],
  }
},
```

I'm getting the following:

```
C:\path\to\app\node_modules\@craco\craco\lib\loaders.js:34
    rules.some((rule, index) => {
          ^

TypeError: rules.some is not a function
```